# Facebook for Blackberry API available for 4.6.0 ?

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I've been trying to add the facebook features (Facebook for Blackberry API) to a Blackberry Application but once I add all the files, I get errors from missing libraries in version 4.6.0 (which is the one that I must use as a base and, seems these libraries are only in versions 5.0 and onwards).

I'd like to know if anyone has had this problem and, if so, how have you solved it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Facebook SDK uses BrowserField class that is available from 5.0 OS only. I think it can be rewritten with using `RenderingApplication` that will allow to use it on lower OSs. But I remember there was performance issue with it on 6+ devices. So it will add more complexity to support two versions.
So probably there are more hidden issues. But it's better to ask authors of FB SDK.